# Error updating Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates

Ive been trying to update my Ubuntu 16.04 and get these messages.

```
** (appstreamcli:3132): WARNING **: No origin found for file archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_dep11_Components-i386.yml.gz
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
Reading package lists... Error!
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55
W: GPG error: http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.2/ubuntu trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6856E1DB1AC82609
W: The repository 'http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.2/ubuntu trusty InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_dep11_Components-i386.yml.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55


ls /etc/apt/sou*

/etc/apt/sources.list  /etc/apt/sources.list.save

/etc/apt/sources.list.d:
gezakovacs-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
gezakovacs-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
gnome3-team-ubuntu-gnome3-staging-xenial.list
gnome3-team-ubuntu-gnome3-staging-xenial.list.save
gnome3-team-ubuntu-gnome3-xenial.list
gnome3-team-ubuntu-gnome3-xenial.list.save
mkusb-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
mkusb-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
stebbins-ubuntu-handbrake-releases-xenial.list
stebbins-ubuntu-handbrake-releases-xenial.list.save
vala-team-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
vala-team-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
xenial-partner.list
yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-xenial.list
yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-xenial.list.save
```

Is there anything I can do at my end?  Am I still getting important security updates?  I'm not to worried about a few packages here or there, just more interested if there are security issues.  Thanks in advance.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT1  Full verbatim output from  sudo apt-get update

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease            
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]               
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu xenial InRelease      
Get:10 http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.2/ubuntu trusty InRelease [2,891 B]     
Ign:10 http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.2/ubuntu trusty InRelease               
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages          
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en_AU      
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en         
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/vala-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Hit:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons     
Err:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 DEP-11 Metadata   
  Hash Sum mismatch
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages          
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en_AU      
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en         
Fetched 250 kB in 9s (25.3 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Error!
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55
W: GPG error: http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.2/ubuntu trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6856E1DB1AC82609
W: The repository 'http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.2/ubuntu trusty InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_dep11_Components-i386.yml.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: `gnome3-team-ubuntu-gnome3-xenial.list` `gnome3-team-ubuntu-gnome3-xenial.list.save`  -- these lists are duplicated or did you copy them twice. also open etc/apt/sources.list  -- line 6 and 55 are duplicates.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get update`? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks ravery,  not duplicated by copy and paste,  output as is.  Something to do with target source configured multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are currently using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Xenial Xerus

To answer your second question:

Yes, you are still getting security updates and will continue getting updates until early 2021.

16.04 is a LTS release, so instead of only getting updates for 9 months, it gets 5 years of updates. These LTS releases come out every two years.

Source: https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life